# Groovy - Stored procedures that returns an OracleTypes.ARRAY

Tags: groovy-sql

I have an issue with Groovy SQL while calling a Stored procedure which returns OracleTypes.ARRAY  as output parameter.

## Java Code (Working fine):

```
callableStatement.registerOutParameter(37, OracleTypes.ARRAY, DEVICE_RAW_DATA_ARRAY);
```

OracleTypes.ARRAY  registerOutParameter was configured in  JDBC(callableStatement), it was working  fine.
 where as calling the same Stored procedure from Groovy SQL i am getting the following exception "java.sql.SQLException: ORA-03115: unsupported network datatype or representation"

## Groovy Code:

```
import groovy.sql.Sql

def sqlStr = "{call prometheus.PKG_Device_FP_TLDID.SP_Save_Device_FP_Get_TLDID(?,?,?,?,?,?)}"

def params = [  ID_IN,
        Request_ID_IN,  
        Session_ID_IN,      
        Sql.NUMERIC, 
            Sql.VARCHAR, 
            Sql.ARRAY   // ARRAY Type output parameter -- Here I am getting Exception "java.sql.SQLException: ORA-03115: unsupported network datatype or representation" //

]
```

I tried with different DATA TYPES LIKE  Sql.ARRAY // OracleTypes.ARRAY // Sql.OracleTypes.ARRAY   and other types.

Could you please suggest me the equivalent DATA TYPE for the OracleTypes.ARRAY  in Groovy SQL.

Thank you !!